# Setting up WingIDE to debug Flask project

Tags: python, wing-ide

Setting up Flask project in WingIDE:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    if 'WINGDB_ACTIVE' in os.environ:
        app.debug = False
    app.run()
```

returns this error:

```
  File "g:\PyDev\quick\testes.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Comment: Do you use virtual environments?

Comment: Thanks, will look at that now.

Comment: I am out of luck, when trying to set virtualenv, Wing fails:
'Failed to create virtualenv: Could not run C:\Users\recur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\virtualenv.exe: timed out'

But runing the same line in the cmd prompt, it succeeds and creates \ven and I can activate it with:
'code'ven\scripts\activate'code'

Comment: OK, instead of creating a new virtual env I switched to using the one created via console, and now I can access the HTML templates etc.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think Wing is using a different Python installation by default, rather than the one that has Flask installed into it.  You can point Wing to the right one from the Python Executable property in Project Properties.  If you use a virtualenv, then that would be the virtualenv's python.  Typically (in either case) this is the full path in sys.executable (after 'import sys') if you run that Python interactively outside of Wing.

In Wing 6.1.2+ you can also create a new virtualenv from Project > New Project, if creating your Wing project coincides with starting a new project in general.  But if you already have your project, just change the Python Executable.

Comment: Yes, the Python Executable way worked for me (= using the Python executable in a previous created \venv\scripts\).
Creating a new venv from within Project> New always timed out.

Comment: Try applying patches in Wing 6.1.2 with Check for Updates in the Help menu.  The fact that it's running virtualenv and not python -m venv seems to indicate you don't have updates installed.